# Point mongoos.connect at localhost mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am studying the MEAN stack by using [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular).  But the tutorial connects to a remote mongodb installation.  I have MongoDB running in the CentOS7 localhost.

**How do I alter the mongoose connect line in server.js from the tutorial link above to connect to a localhost database instead of a remote database?
 Here is the current line from `server.js` that needs to be changed to point to the localhost mongodb:**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:nodeuser@mongo.onmodulus.net:27017/uwO3mypu');
```

A specific mongodb database has not been created yet.  Do I need to create that also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly new at Mongo to, but I know how to connect to a local db. Basically I had to do the following:

- Download the latest version of mongodb from https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community (according to your settings)
- Once installed, I've created a folder that will be containing my DB.
- Use a command line instance to start mongo like this:

`mongod --dbpath [YOUR_DB_PATH]`

- Created a DB `use mydb`
- With that you should have already a `mongodb` db instance looking for connections on default port. So you can change that line for this:

`mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb');`

Again, this is really basic and it is creating a mongo DB connection with all default options. So this will keep you rolling, but you may need to dig a bit more for custom options.

Hope this helps